# Need to show all rows using Mysql query with Group By

Tags: mysql

Table fields-

```
[id, name, roll, studentId, score]
```

Table-

```
----------------------
|1 |tanvir |6 | 1| 20|  
|2 |tanvir |6 | 1| 40|
|3 |tanvir |6 | 1| 80|
|4 |tanvir |6 | 1| 50|
----------------------
```

Query-
->SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `score`;

Output-

```
 ----------------------
 |1 |tanvir |6 | 1| 20|  
 ----------------------
```

I need to show all scores, not only the first score.

My desired Output-

```
 ----------------------------------
 |1 |tanvir |6 | 1| 20, 40, 80, 50|  
 ----------------------------------
```

Comment: all score you mean sum of all ?

Comment: add desired output also

Comment: mention your requirement Properly

Comment: No.     I want all scores not as sum.     I need all them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, roll, studentId, GROUP_CONCAT(score) as score FROM tbl_name GROUP BY studentId
```

Comment: The question appears to use comma-space as a separator, so the call should be `group_concat(score separator ', ')`.